# Overriding mediaquery css rules in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, media-queries

Here is the sample code that I have which shows `#data` in  `md-12` or `sm-6` based on the browser's width. in Some conditions (like the special mode of preview that I want to implement and will be triggered by JS) I want to override the `#data` rendering rules to renders only the `col-md-12` even on small screens.

Please note that I don't want to remove any classes from DOM, and looking for a solution to use `.parent` (I can add any class to this element) to override its child rendering rules.

In other words, I want to force bootstrap to shows content in `md` mode and ignores the browsers' width.

I also wondered to know if this problem can be solved by changing the `viewport` value?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="data" class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How does the element know it is in the special condition?

Do you dynamically add a class on the `.parent` element (for example `.preview`) or on one of its parents?
If so, a possible solution could be to define a css rule with a higher specificity like `.preview #data` where you set the properties as in `.col-md-12` (or just those which need to be restored).

Following are possible examples:

```
/* media query of .col-sm-6 */
@media (min-width: 576px) { 

  /* this is if you only need to override #data element */
  .preview #data {
    /* properties from .col-md-12 */
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  /* this is if you need to override all occurences of .col-sm-6 inside a .preview element */
  .preview .col-sm-6 {
    /* properties from .col-md-12 */
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

}
```

Comment: yes, I can add class to `.parent` . Do you mean I need to re-define bootstrap `md` and `sm` rules for `preview` class ?

Comment: Yes, you can redefine `sm` rules with a higher specificity selector, which will override the original `sm` one, but only when the `.preview` class is applied to the parent element. When you remove the `.preview` class, the original behaviour is restored. I edited my answer to show some examples.